# Dont fragment flag for IPv6 packets in Linux using C++

Tags: c++, ipv6, icmp

I can not set the "don't fragment" flag for the IPv6/ICMPv6 packets. I am doing PMTUD and I want to force the router to drop packets bigger then the MTU. Using setsockopt with IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER is not working.

```
int on = IPV6_PMTUDISC_DO; // tried also IPV6_PMTUDISC_PROBE
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER, &on, sizeof(on));
```

result:
[image: wireshark]

I also can not use setosckopt with `IPV6_DONTFRAG` as described in *Unix-Linux Addison-Wesley - Stevens2003 - Unix Network Programming* because I have the `netinet/in6.h` header included and `IPV6_DONTFRAG` is defined in `linux/in6.h`. Including `linux/in6.h` in my source code causes these redefinition errors.

```
In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:30:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
                 from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:198:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:46:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sockaddr_in6’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
                 from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:239:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct sockaddr_in6’ In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:54:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct ipv6_mreq’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
                 from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:275:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct ipv6_mreq’ make: *** [mypmtud] Error 1
```

Environment: Ubuntu 12.10 on VirtualBox 4.26 and GNS3 for the virtual network. The virtual Cisco C3660 router has just basic configuration: ip, ipv6 address, no shut and set mtu.

**EDIT:** 
I need the IPv6 stack/OS kernel to drop packets that are bigger than the link MTU or to signalize "this packet needs fragmentation". How can I achieve this behavior?

I tried `setsockopt` with `IPV6_DONTFRAG` (defined it in my code `#define IPV6_DONTFRAG 62` ), `setsockopt` with `IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER`, `int on = IPV6_PMTUDISC_DO` and `setsockopt` with `IPV6_RECVPATHMTU`.

But I am not getting the `PACKET TOO BIG` reply or `ancillary data` with `cmsg_level == IPPROTO_IPV6` and `cmsg_type == IPV6_PATHMTU.`

Part of my code:

```
/** sending ICMP packet*/
 if (((length = sendto(mysocket, packet, lengthBuff, 0, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen)) < 0) && (errno == EMSGSIZE)){

     // works for IPv4, doesn't work with IPv6
     cout << "changing maxBuff and lengthBuff size" << endl;

        maxBuff = lengthBuff;
        lengthBuff = (minBuff + maxBuff) / 2;

        if (packet) {
            delete(packet);
            packet = NULL;
        }


    } else if (length < 0){

     cerr << "Error: sending data." << endl;

            freeaddrinfo(result);
            close(mysocket);

            if (packet) {
                delete(packet);
                packet = NULL;
            }

            exit(1);
    } else if(((recvmsg(mysocket, &msg, 0)) != -1) && (errno != EINTR)) {

        // reading ancillary dada as described in  *Unix-Linux Addison-Wesley - Stevens2003 - Unix Network Programming, page 736*
        cmsgh = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);    

        if(cmsgh != NULL) {
            cout << "getting msg " << endl;
            cout << "msg len " << msg.msg_controllen << endl;


            if(cmsgh->cmsg_level == IPPROTO_ICMPV6 && cmsgh->cmsg_type == IPV6_PATHMTU)
            {
                cout << "CMSGHEADER - GOOD" << endl;
                //mtustruct = CMSG_DATA(&msg); 

            maxBuff = lengthBuff;
            lengthBuff = (minBuff + maxBuff) / 2;

            if (packet) {
                delete(packet);
                packet = NULL;
            }

            }
            else{

                cout << "different ancillary data. " << endl;
                cout << " level " << cmsgh->cmsg_level << " type " << cmsgh->cmsg_type << endl;
            }
        }

    } else {

        cout << "no ERROR with sendto and no RESCVMSG" << endl;
    } 

    /** receiving ICMP data */
    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int retval; // select

        FD_ZERO(&mySet);
        FD_SET(mysocket, &mySet);

        retval = select(mysocket + 1, &mySet, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (retval == -1) {
            cerr << "select failed" << endl;
            //break;
            exit(1);
        } else if (retval) {
            if ((length = recvfrom(mysocket, buffer, MAX, 0, result->ai_addr, &(result->ai_addrlen))) == -1) {
                cerr << "Error: receiving data." << endl;
            } else {
                icmpRec = (struct icmp6_hdr*) buffer;

                if((icmpRec->icmp6_type == ICMP6_PACKET_TOO_BIG)) {


                    cout << "next hop MTU: " << ntohl(icmpRec->icmp6_mtu) << endl;
                    maxBuff = ntohl(icmpRec->icmp6_mtu);                       

                } else if ((icmpRec->icmp6_type == ICMP6_ECHO_REPLY) && (ntohs(icmpRec->icmp6_id) == pid) && (ntohs(icmpRec->icmp6_seq) == (seq - 1))) {
                    cout << "code " << ntohs(icmpRec->icmp6_code) << endl;
                    cout << "ICMP ECHO REPLY" << endl;
                    minBuff = lengthBuff;

                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT2:**
I realized, `setsockopt` with defined `IPV6_DONTFRAG` is not working for me, but `setsockopt` with `IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER` is working for the own interface. The eth1 interface MTU is 1500 (default) and if `sendto` wants to send packets with bigger size, `errno` is set to `EMSGSIZE`. Also after some time I get `PACKET TOO BIG` message for these not send messages fom the **own kernel/OS**.

My real problem is, I am **not** getting (Ubuntu 12.10 running on VirtualBox 4.2.6) `PACKET TOO BIG` messages from the virtual router (Cisco c3660) running on GNS3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and I want to force the router to drop packets bigger then the MTU

In IPv6 packets bigger than the MTU will always be dropped. Unlike in IPv4, IPv6 routers don't fragment packets. Instead, the source is expected to perform PMTU and:

- Have the transport layer protocol produce adequate-sized datagrams
- Fragment packets **locally** and attach a fragment extension

Linux does indeed have full support for `IPV6_DONTFRAG` (I think it was added in 2.6.35) although it only affects local behavior.

Comment: Why is Wireshark showing me a fragmented packet from the router to the PC? Is it a "bug"? and why is the source **and** destination address of the "Packet too big" packet my PC? Shouldn't it be the router?

Comment: @MatejKoleják I can only *speculate* if you provide a portion of the trace. Why don't you show more of it ? Perhaps give us the full pcap.

Comment: @MatejKoleják And you obtained this with a simple `ping6` ?

Comment: no, it's my program, that is sending IPv6 packet with ICMv6 header and data.

Comment: @MatejKoleják And you used the IPV6_DONTFRAG ? Are you sending only one packet ?

Comment: I used the "IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER" with "IPV6_PMTUDISC_DO" because I can not use IPV6_DONTFRAG as described in OP. I am trying to send more packets, but for the other i get "Packet too big" replys. I still think I am doing the PMTUD for IPv6 wrong.

Comment: OK. I think I know what is causing my problems. _By default, the IPv6 stack will fragment outgoing packets to the path MTU. An application such as traceroute may not want this automatic fragmentation, to discover the path MTU on its own._ Source: Unix-Linux Addison-Wesley - Stevens2003 - Unix Network Programming. I don't want the IPv6 stack to automatically fragment outgoing packets. How can I achieve this without using setsockopt with "IPV6_DONTFRAG"? Because I can not use "linux/in6.h".

Comment: I marked cnicutars answer as accepted because it's the correct answer for the original post. But my problem remains. I'm not getting ICMPv6 "packet too big" messages from the virtual router.

Comment: @MatejKoleják I'll compile your code tomorrow to see what happens. If need be I'll fire up my old dynamips to reproduce it.

Comment: That would be great. Its not complete, if you need also the socket, ICMPv6 creation etc. tell me.